# How to recover Oracle Virtual Box after file move?

Tags: virtualbox

I have moved all my virtual machine files from drive D: to drive V:

When I start `Oracle Virtual Box` it displays warning

[image]

If I press `Check` button it opens `Virtual Media Manager` window, which is absolutely useless and confusing, since does not allow to "manage" anything.

[image]

It's `Modify` button is deceptive, since does not allow to fix the path to disk image.

Similar thing happens in main window: all machine entries are red and no any apparent option to fix the paths.

[image]

How to overcome?

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the current VM images from the VirtualBox menu and then re-import them individually (i.e. double click each `.vbox` file to import it), or you can edit the [`VirtualBox.xml`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html) settings file that stores the location of the images in one sweep. The xml file should have entries similar to the following:

```
<MachineRegistry>
    <MachineEntry uuid="{719bb098-982b-4549-901f-57b7c4aec87f}" src="D:\path\to\image.vbox"/>
    <MachineEntry uuid="{71e68333-5b48-4eeb-a336-259117f60af4}" src="D:\path\to\other.vbox"/>
</MachineRegistry>
```

Here you can just change the `D:\...` to `V:\...`. Be sure to do this when the VirtualBox main window is completely closed or the changes won't go through (since VBox will save the file when it closes, thus reverting any changes made).

Also note that if you have `.vbox` files that reference virtual disks via explicit paths, you'll need to ensure those are updated to reference the new paths as well; as an example from a `.vbox` file:

```
<HardDisks>
    <!-- this VDI will need to be edited to reference the new path -->
    <HardDisk uuid="{ab4cdcbd-8ea5-474a-b55b-913662f42bb5}" location="D:\path\to\virtual_disk.vdi" format="VDI" type="Normal"/>
    <!-- this VDI does not need to be edited -->
    <HardDisk uuid="{ab4cdcbd-8eff-474a-b55b-913662f42bb5}" location="relative_path.vdi" format="VDI" type="Normal"/>
</HardDisks>
```

If you created your VirtualBox images with the default paths, then this shouldn't be an issue, but if this is the case, it might be quicker to just remove the entry and re-import it.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows when all the machines were powered off I had moved

```
"%USERPROFILE%\VirtualBox VMs" to "Y:\VirtualBox VMs"
```

After making sure all the VM services were not running I edited

```
"%USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml"
```

Changing the old location to the new.
Restarted the services and was able to power up the machines without any issues.
I also changed where new machines would be created in the VirtualBox Manager under -> File -> Preferences -> General